# update all rows where column1 > column2

Tags: mysql

Is it somehow possible to make a MySQL command doing this:
`UPDATE FROM players WHERE column1 > column2 SET column2 = column1`

Any ideas how this can be done?
Or do I have to run 2 mysql commands? One selecting, and one updating?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done, you just need to fix your syntax, it should be:

```
UPDATE players SET column2 = column1 WHERE column1 > column2;
```

MySQL 5 manual on [`UPDATE Syntax`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

> Single-table syntax:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

> Multiple-table syntax:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

Answer (score 3):

you dont need to `select` data in order to update it. you can directly use the `update`.

```
UPDATE players SET column2 = column1 WHERE column1 > column2;
```